# Will Dual WAN improve video conferencing?

Tags: networking, video-streaming

When from my relatives house in South America I have problems with video conferencing. Video will freeze, words will be lost, etc. The connection is intermittent. Often times I can switch from one ISP to another (cable internet to 3g) and the problems clear up, however this takes time and isn't ideal.

Was thinking about purchasing a dual wan router and getting two ISPs hooked up to make for better video conferencing. I primarily use teams. My hope is that the transition from one ISP to another could be pretty seamless. Before spending the money on a router and signing a second agreement with another ISP I wanted to check with folks here to see if anyone has experience with this or would know if it's a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two internet services does not mean things will work twice as fast or twice as reliably. Switching ISPs isn't usually difficult.

Comment: You may be able to tell certain applications to always use certain connections, but it depends on your operating system and the tools available to that OS. https://www.google.com/search?q=force+application+to+use+specific+network+interface

Comment: Thanks for the info but not what I'm asking. Question is around if dual wan is using ISP 1 and video call starts to have issues, how seamless would it be to switch over to the second ISP? How will the video call be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, long answer is probably not. Middle answer is maybe.

The most important thing you can do is have a reliable connection. If you can't have one reliable connection then two unreliable connections won't likely deliver what you are looking for.

It is relatively easy to detect a fully dropped connection and failover to another WAN.  It is much more complex to determine rules for an unsatisfactory connection and switch back and forth.  If both connections suffer from performance issues, latency etc. the logic would be more challenging.

You should first assume that if you switch WAN routes mid-connection you will disrupt your session. It could be a mere interruption to a more significant disruption.  Changing IPs during an athenticated session necessitates re-authentication as the alternative would be risking man in the middle attacks.

Some of the disruption you are experiencing may also be related to the platform. If the video has hung or frozen there can be a delay while the platform times out before it acknowledges that the call has ended/failed and allows it to be reestablished regardless whether it is the same ISP or you've failed over to another.

Importantly, most services won't benefit from dual WAN for speed as the real benefit is achieved under load of multiple users or services (businesses) where the traffic can be balanced between connections. i.e. Once a connection is established on one WAN or the other, it will usually continue to use that same connection in both directions for that session even if the other connection becomes faster.  To further clarify you would not expect a file to be downloaded to your PC at twice the speed.  If you have 100 concurrent users having 50 routed through one ISP and 50 through another might have value.  The exception is when the ISP itself does the bonding like some telcos will bond multiple lines to increase throuput

The biggest benefit you would get from multi Wan is having a fail over ISP ready to go.  Assuming that your primary ISP "mostly" works, you should expect your fail over ISP to be mostly idle 24/7/365.

You might do well to do some additional investigation as to what is actually going on during these outages.  Dropped packets? Latency? Speed? Something else.  That would help inform your next steps. Different video conferencing platforms may handle the network issues differently and understanding the problem space might also help direct you a different platform.

Even your connection to the network (Ethernet vs WiFi) are factors.  If testing and isolating the necessary info seems challenging, managing multi-wan for all but fail over will likely be more so.

There is some anecdotal evidence that Google Meet may work well with low bandwidth connections but I can't confirm.